# Playing AES encrypted streams in Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, aes

I am trying to stream AES encrypted HLS content in the Android MediaPlayer, however the content never loads.

The path to the .m3u8 file (hosted on akamai) includes extra parameters in the url (for decryption and authentication purposes) which are parsed into a uri, then the uri is passed into the MediaPlayer.

I can manually put the url with these extra parameters into a web browser and retrieve the correct m3u8 files no problem, I've even tried pointing quicktime on my mac to the url and it plays great but the MediaPlayer on android does not seem to know what to do with it.

Does anyone have any pointers on how it is possible to play encrypted HLS streams using MediaPlayer?

Edit: the calls are done over https and I am targeting android 4.0 (ICS) minimum

Comment: This might help: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673932/hls-with-aes-128-encryption-on-android-ice-cream-sandwich/13393936#13393936) In my experience support is still quite new and device-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'm actually targeting ICS as a minimum so I don't think I'd have a problem there, I have a feeling that because all the calls and data are retrieved via https there's an issue there.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm trying to find an example of it as well..

Comment: Yes I did, the problem was not Android, it was the authentication in Akamai. AES encrypted streams work fine on Android.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just to verify; the problem was not Android, it was the authentication in Akamai. AES encrypted streams work fine on Android out of the box.